# Caffe: train, validation and test split

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, caffe, conv-neural-network

I've been using caffe for a while, with some success, but I have noticed in examples given that there is only ever a two way split on the data set with `TRAIN` and `TEST` phases, where the `TEST` set seems to act as a validation set.

Ideally I would like to have three sets, so that once the model is trained, I can save it and test it on a completely new test set - stored in a completed separate lmdb folder. Does anyone have any experience of this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Differentiating between validation and testing is made to imply that hyperparameters may be tuned to the validation set while nothing is fitted to the test set in any way.
`caffe` doesn't optimize anything but the weights, and since the test is only there for evaluation, it does exactly as expected.

Assuming you're tuning hyper parameters between solver optimization runs. The lmdb passed to `caffe` for testing is really the validation set. If you're done with tuning your hyperparameters and do one more solver optimization with an lmdb for testing that holds data never used in previous runs. That last lmdb is your test set.

Since caffe doesn't optimize hyperparameters, its test set is what it is, a test set. It's possible to come up with a some python code around the solver optimization calls that iterates through hyperparameter values. After it's done it can swap in a new lmdb with unseen data to tell you about how well the network generalizes with it.

I don't recommend modifying caffe for an explicit val/test distinction. You don't even have to do anything elaborate with setting up the prototxt file for the solver and network definition. You can do the val/test swap at the end by simply moving the val lmdb somewhere else and moving the test lmdb in its place using `shutil.copy(src, dst)`

Comment: thanks, this makes sense. im not sure about using shutil to copy over existing databases, do you have an idea of how to point a trained caffe model to a new database? thanks.

Comment: @ypx, I have a question for you to be more clear. In the caffe tutorial for MNIST dataset, so "mnist-test-leveldb" is actually testing dataset or validation dataset?

Comment: Caffe doesn't distinguish between test and validation. Validation set means that you excluded a subset of the data from the training set but tried to improve accuracy/loss by changing hyper parameters (e.g. learning rate, more hidden nodes,...). The test set is a third subset that tells you how good your network is on what you selected is your best hyper parameter configuration.

Comment: @ypx: Thanks alot. 
I created 3 datasets as you pointed out. train_lmdb, val_lmdb, and test_lmdb. 
I trained using the train/val datasets. now I dont know how to get the performance for the test set. 
Do I need to train from beginning with train/test this time and compare the results to former training? (this doesnt make sense!)
or use a pre-trained model from train/val stage and then test on new test-set. if this is the later one, how can I do it?